Login exists locally in databases, but not globally
I've inherited an existing TFS implementation.    In the TFS databases, there is a user called  VssfAdmin with dbowner membership.
This user is NOT listed in the global branch Security -> Logins
update...
CREATE USER [VssfAdmin] WITHOUT LOGIN WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
What is the purpose of this login?
How is it used in the TFS system?

There could be so many reasons for it; this isn't an answerable question. USERs, however, don't have to have a mapped LOGIN. Also, just bceause there's no LOGIN with the same name doesn't mean that there's no mapped LOGIN; CREATE USER jsdhvfjoas23780ipASbvoasdf FOR LOGIN MyLogin; is valid.

All reasons above  but also it could just be an orphaned user.  Where they cleaned up/deleted the user from the server but not the database.  Or the DB migrated to a new server and never had the server login created (orphaned just in a different way).

Tom, thanks for the response....   do you have answers to the questions being asked?

It's common to create a user without a login for schema/object ownership purposes.

No one can answer this question because that account isn't a standard part of any TFS installation; it's something that someone in your organization did at some point.
